# How can I reboot the iPhone programmatically from within my application?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to trigger a reboot of the iPhone programmatically from within your application, either using public or private API?

Comment: Illeagally?  Break into their house and reboot it yourself.  Voilà.

Comment: I removed "illegally" because it's illegal... ^_^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to Programmatically Reboot iOS Device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366813/way-to-programmatically-reboot-ios-device)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there is no legal way. Mostly because of security reasons. What happens if they allow and somebody trying to write some virus. But illegally, yes, it can, Cydia can do that so we can technically do that

Comment: how can i do that with private api ?can u tell the procedure?

Comment: if you are willing to use jailbreak techniques, there is at least one way (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419678/iphone-reboot-programmatically/).  I describe a way to do this by hooking into SBSettings.

Comment: Not sure why I get minus here?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, u cant reboot the phone without user's confirmation. Apple wont allow you to reboot iphone without user knowing it. This is something which violates Apple's terms.

For rebooting the device, u need to execute a file present in the iphone. This will do the trick. Now comes the hard part, the name and path to the file is something for u to figure out.

HAppy programming!

EMX Dev

Answer (score 2):

There is private API for this, but Apple would never approve your app on the AppStore.

Comment: how can i get this api plz tell

Comment: You can get the headers for the private frameworks, just google it - but as I said, Apple will never approve an app that uses private frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

If you jailbreak your iPhone, you can download Terminal and issue the reboot command.

Comment: he just said - you can issue the reboot command - but that's for jailbroken phones only.

Comment: the question asked about doing this programmatically.  you apparently cannot call reboot programmatically (e.g. using a system() call), even if your app runs as root.  see my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419678/iphone-reboot-programmatically/)

Answer (score 0):

I answered this similar question with a technique that works (jailbroken phones) as long as you make your package depend on SBSettings:

[iphone reboot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419678/iphone-reboot-programmatically/)