# Restarting an iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 3GS, which I am using for testing etc. Unfortunately its Power button (the one on top right) stopped working, thanks to my son's attempts at baseball pitching practice. Now, if I have to reboot the phone, all I can do is let the battery drain out and then reconnect power. Is it possible to do something programmatically (I will not, of course, submit this as an iPhone App!) without jailbreaking, so I can restart the iPhone when needed? I have an Apple membership so I can write and run these apps on the phone. Any suggestions are appreciated.

I am running iOS 5.1.1 on it currently.

Comment: I *highly* doubt you will be able to do this in an app. In fact, I *hope* you can't. Only thing that comes to mind is something like a restore using iTunes.

Comment: duplicated - http://stackoverflow.com/q/6419678/194544

Comment: Welcome to the jailbreak community my friend !