# Can you include phone shutdown in iOS unit testing?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I was wondering if it was possible to test iOS phone state in your unit testing? Is it possible to shutdown the phone and then turn it back on in your unit test? Is there a third party software that could test this?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a testing framework that will reboot and wait for it to restart before continuing.

Here is some more information: [iphone reboot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419678/iphone-reboot-programmatically)