# Using gdb to dump memory for jailbroken iOS app

Tags: ios, gdb, jailbreak

I'm developing an app to be run on jailbroken devices and I'm a little stuck.

My app requires gdb to dump memory from an app. The problem I have is that creating or modifying files only works within code, when I try and run a command from shell, it won't run as root, and therefore won't let me write outside my sandbox (Which doesn't exist cause the app is for jailbroken devices).

So I have 2 theoretical solutions to my problem.

1) Find a way to run /bin/sh as root *preferred

2) If there's a way to dump memory to the terminal, I can grab with NSData and then create a file for it within my code. However I haven't seen away to do that.

Those are just the 2 ideas I came up with, let me know if this is possible, or if you know another way.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're trying to run shell commands *programmatically*, from your app.  If you're trying to get around the problem with `system()` calls not running as root, even if your app runs as root, [here's one workaround for that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6503158/119114)

Comment: i'd rather not have a dependency like that...even if it is a very popular app. Is there any place at all the user who is running the commands can write?

Comment: First, you're **stuck**, and now you don't want to depend on one of the most widely used (and free) jailbreak apps?  Boy, we got picky in a hurry, didn't we?

Comment: I didn't mean any disrespect, I just was hoping there was another way to do it. It definitely seems like it would solve my problem, but I just want to make sure there isn't another way I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any user can write in the /tmp directory....

I just changed the location to dump memory to /tmp/file.bin and then I can move it however I want through code.