# (Programmatically/Automatically) Removing iOS-Apps

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'm looking for a solution how to remove all installed iOS-Apps from a device. I'm working on a project for iOS-Security. For different analytical stuff on a jail-broken device it's necessary to automatically install a fat bunch of apps, perform all the tests and remove them afterwards to get free space for further applications. The auto installation and test-logic is already done. I only stuck with the apps-removing part.

User installed iOS-Apps are located in `/var/mobile/Applications/`.
Each application has its own randomly named directory e.g. `7654BE30-F438-42CE-98E0-B95264458C49/`.

To proof whether an application is already installed or not my software checks out the `com.apple.mobile.installation.plist` in `/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/`

**I've tried** to remove the binaries of all applications in `/var/mobile/Applications/` and there references in the `com.apple.mobile.installation.plist`. It seems like the iOS generates a new `com.apple.mobile.installation.plist` after each installation-process, so it makes no difference whether I remove all the entries out of `com.apple.mobile.installation.plist` or not. So if I would like to install an application which was already tested someday my software wouln't recognize that it's not installed yet, because it's still listed in `com.apple.mobile.installation.plist`.

I try to find out where the iOS stores all the information about a user installed application. Would appreciate any help or hint to find out the information. Thanks in advance!

Consider I'm working with an jailbroken iDevice, so everything is possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Wipe whole device programmatically**

[Is there a way to programatically restore my iphone to factory settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203001/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-restore-my-iphone-to-factory-settings/15205830#15205830)

**Uninstall some app programmatically**

if you want to uninstall apps, you can use private API "MobileInstallationUninstall". However, it requires entitlement "com.apple.private.mobileinstall.allowedSPI", which you can get, because your device is jailbroken.