# How to delete the app with using the passcode?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

My aim is when i delete the application i need to ask passcode for security reason. That passcode is correct the application will be deleted or else the application will not delete. how to achieve this, even it is possible for jailbreak iPhone not a problem.

This all are achieve our coding in programatically using iPhone sdk.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: May be you missed magic word `Programatically` ?

Comment: Yes i need to do programatically in iPhone application development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AppStore application - Programically**

No way to do it because only the user (or iTunes, or Xcode's Organizer) can remove applications from the device.You have no control via programically.

**AppStore application - Manually:**

You **can't** do it only for a single AppStore application. The reason is they are **Sandboxed.**

This means they are limited in how they can interact with other applications, and the iPhone itself.

You **can do it for the entire applications** that installed on your device via

```
Settings - > General->Restrictions.
```

[image]

**Jailbroken application -  Programically**

if you want to uninstall apps, you can use private API `MobileInstallationUninstall`. However, it requires entitlement `com.apple.private.mobileinstall.allowedSPI`, which you can get, because your device is jailbroken.

**Jailbroken application -  Manually**

You can **jailbreak** the phone and install a jailbreak tweak like **[Locktopus](http://www.howtogeek.com/93688/locktopus-locks-down-individual-apps-on-ios-devices/)** or **[Lockdown](http://thebigboss.org/lockdown-pro-password-protect-your-applications-now-released) Pro.** These let you set a passcode.

Comment: I need to use programatically, In iOS application development

Comment: hmm,,, you have to mention it in your question.

Comment: Yes now added comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is possible to do jailbroken iPhone app?

Comment: oh.. wait.. Im looking on

Comment: You should have given credit for part of your answer, which you got from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16322020/381233

Answer (score 1):

No need for a jailbreak. Simply go into Settings>General>Restrictions and don't allow "Deleting Apps". Restrictions are protected using a password just like your lock passcode (although it can be a different code if you would like).

Comment: Here i need to use iPhone application development with programatically for particular app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do with help of ‘AppLocker’ Password Protects Your Individual iOS Apps

Further more details:

[Applocker](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/10/24/applocker/)

You can protect your photo and app from the second link

[Password Protect iPhone Photos Or Any Other App](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-password-protect-iphone-photos-or-any-other-app/)