# Reboot a device from phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Is there a way to reboot a device with phonegap/cordova? How would I go about doing this? I think it may not be possible on an ipad/iphone but it would be on androids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First basically it can't be done unless your device is rooted/jailbreaken (depending are we talking about **Android** or **iOS**).

Now comes the fun part even if you have rooted/jailbreaken device you will not be able to do that unless you can do some **Java**/**Objective C** development.

Basically **Phonegap** plugin don't exist simply because this functionality is usually not needed unless you are doing something with your phone on a basic level. **But** if you have enough knowledge you can do it by your self. **Phonegap** plugin can be created very easy, and you can find more in this [**tutorial**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html). What you want to do is create a simple plugin that will execute **Java**/**Objective C** code when you need it.

#### Android/Java example :

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Could not reboot", ex);
}
```

#### iOS/Objective C example

Unfortunately I don't have that much experience with this functionality on iOS so you will need to trust this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6503158/1848600)**.

Comment: Thanks!! Android was what I had in mind. I was a bit unsure on IOS due to the requirement of being jailbroken but Ill give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed same functionality, made a plugin based on Gajotres example:
[cordova-plugin-reboot](https://github.com/fadeit/cordova-plugin-reboot)