# Phonegap - Shut Down Device?

Tags: cordova, device, shutdown

I have recently started using Phonegap. I want to make an application that will make the device shut down after a period of time; timer. However, I looked on Google but found no solution for my problem:

**Make the device shut down**

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way of doing it. These isn't any plugin for that.

Now you can write custom plugin to use native code to achieve that functionality. But..... there are conditions applied. Some of them are like `phone has to be rooted` or `You need to sign your app with the System Firmware Key.`

You can view more details answers in these links

[Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone)

[Reboot a device from phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376144/reboot-a-device-from-phonegap)

Comment: Would you be able to help me write a custom plugin for it? Fantastic answer though.