# How to build an app (packaged as IPA file) that can install deb package on jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ipa, deb

I downloaded an IPA file from http://m.qq.com/ , and install it to my jailbroken iPhone with iFunBox, run and after some self configurating, it rebooted automatically, and when the device restarted, a deb that was built in that IPA file was installed.

I knew that installing deb packages requires root privilege, but the internal executable in that IPA file is normal application, so it made me confused.

PS: SBSettings is not installed on my iPhone, so the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419678/iphone-reboot-programmatically/6503158#6503158) cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Did you have MobileSubstrate installed before you installed this app?  Disassembled this app - very interesting but important parts are obfuscated. I've found `killall SpringBoard`, `/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries` and various other clues so my guess is this app somehow installs MobileSubstrate dylib that helps with installing everything else. This dylib may even execute that same app but with elevated privilages because there are clues that app checks permissions it has. It also tries to copy deb files in cydia AutoInstall directory which has write permissions only for root.

Comment: My iPhone has MobileSubstrate installed, the app also has mobilesubstrate deb file built in.

Comment: The first thing I wonder is that as a user app, how could it reboot the iPhone ?

Comment: That the least of my concerns. The reason it reboots iPhone is to install deb files from Cydia AutoInstall directory. So main question is - how can it copy anything in it because only root has write permissions for it. AppStore apps run as mobile. It needs root permissions and my quess is it somehow installs MobileSubstrate tweak, then uses `killall SpringBoard` (which works from mobile user) to inject it. Then it somehow obtains root permissions in order to copy debs in Cydia AutoInstall. Once you've got root permissions (which you absolutely must have) rebooting iPhone is no problem.

Comment: So could you please try to install this app from scratch but without MobileSubstrate already installed. Disassembly tells me that it should open Cydia on MobileSubstrate page. There is no way it can install MobileSubstrate without Cydia or some other app with root permissions.