# Is there an equivalent in iOS, for a text based app? (Like a C++ console app)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am curious to know if there is an equivalent on iOS, of a "terminal/console" application.

Like the ones that you make in C++, when all that you need is to launch an app, let it do some operation (like testing, benchmarking, activities that does not require user intervention).

is possible to do so? If yes, is there a tutorial that show how to structure such app? Since it won't use UIKit nor any other graphic framework; I assume that you write it like you would write a regular C++ console application?

I am aware that iOS does not have termina, so it won't be interactive, but this doesn't mean that it cannot execute operation and report results; which can be saved in the common document area, and synced down with iTunes.

Comment: Use a single-page app and `NSLog`?..

Comment: I would like to not display anything on the device. I can eventually do it in this way, but is it worth to load a ton of frameworks that I don't need nor use?

Comment: I doubt that you'd ever get such an app into the app store.

Comment: I can modify it to get to the store; in the meantime I need to make it first :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone reboot programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419678/iphone-reboot-programmatically)

Comment: Im-possible duplicate? What I was asking is something totally different from rebooting an iphone.