# Create iOS Jailbreak for Rebooting, restarting springboard etc

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I've been searching a lot and just cannot find anything. I want to know how I can make an iOS app that has buttons that when clicked execute a terminal command, such as, killall SpringBoard, or Rebbot, or UICache. Does anyone know how to make a button execute a command like that?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419678/iphone-reboot-programmatically/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the source of PowerApp https://github.com/Dave1482/PowerApp